# Isomorphism between quotients of two variable formal power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-power-series, ring-isomorphism

$k$ is a field whose characteristic is not $2$, and $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2, g(x,y)=x^2+x^3-y^2$.

**Exercise.** Show that $k[[x,y]]/(f)\simeq k[[x,y]]/(g)$.

So far, I've shown the following.

- $k[[x,y]]$ is an integral domain.
- $\sqrt{1+x}\in k[[x,y]]^{\times}$, $g(x,y)=(x\sqrt{1+x}+y)(x\sqrt{1+x}-y)$
- The two ideals $(x+y)$, $(x-y)$ are not coprime.

I was trying to use the Chinese remainder theorem. But since the two ideals are not coprime, it cannot help.
Now I'm trying to use the fundamental homomorphism theorem.

If you can answer this exercise, please help me.

Comment: You can just write the isomorphism down explicitly. It needs to send $x$ to $x \sqrt{1 + x}$ and $y$ to $y$.

Comment: I'm struggling to show that homomorphism is isomorphism..

Comment: Show that every formal power series of the form $x + \text{higher order terms}$ has a compositional inverse.

Comment: I completed the proof! Thanks a lot!!